# Windows Forms App, output text?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you output text in a windows form app?  I have a List like this:

```
List<float> List;
```

It has a bunch of numbers in it...I would like to output them in one column.  Can you output them to a richtextbox or a textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a TextBox, or a ListBox, or just about anything else.